# C# Convert REG_MULTI_SZ value in text file to String

Tags: c#, registry

I am not a trained programmer but I do write some code (so be gentle).  I am working on code to read a registry file and store the values in an SQL database.  We have different registry files we push depending on the computer build.  And while I could keep a folder of registry files, having a database makes it easier to compare differences and keep track of changes to the registry settings.

That said, I can easily read string and dword values but I'm having trouble with the REG_MULTI_SZ values. For example, how do I convert this in the registry file?

**"SampleMS"=hex(7):54,00,45,00,53,00,54,00,00,00,44,00,41,00,54,00,41,00,00,00,\
  00,00**
*(This is 2 lines of text in the registry file so I know i have to account or that.)*

To the actual value shown in regedit of:
**TEST
DATA**

I've read several examples of hex to byte array and byte array to string, but all that seems to do is give me the hex values in a string format like "5400450053..."

If this has already been answered somewhere and I missed it, my apologies.  Any examples or code snippets are appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Don't you mean "REG_MULTI_SZ"?

Comment: Also the data you have looks like binary (REG_BINARY), not strings.

Comment: Sorry, yes.  REG_MULTI_SZ.  It's not a REG_BINARY although it appears to be binary data.  It's the value that goes into the text file when you export the key.  So my REG_MULTI_SZ is named SampleMS and the data in that value is TEST DATA on 2 separate lines.

Comment: Well, those bytes appear to be UTF16 representations of characters. A MULTI_SZ contains multiple null-terminated strings terminated by an empty string (or, if you like by two null terminating characters, but technically the first of those "belongs" to the previous string). You've shown us two strings of 4 characters each (plus null characters and the end)

Comment: OK. So my guess would be I need to convert 54,00 to 2 decimal equivalents and then get the ASCII character of the decimal value?  And I'd throw away the 00 unless there are 2 in a row and that indicates a new line?  This doesn't have to perform quickly, just work.

Comment: No, if you need this to work with any data, you can't assume it'll only contain characters in the ASCII subset of Unicode. I've provided an answer outlining the steps to take and options along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, those bytes appear to be UTF16 representations of characters. A MULTI_SZ contains multiple null-terminated strings terminated by an empty string (or, if you like by two null terminating characters, but technically the first of those "belongs" to the previous string). You've shown us two strings of 4 characters each (plus null characters and the end)

So, steps to take - take each pair of hex characters and turn those into a byte (plenty of examples for doing this around). Then take this array of bytes and using [`System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.7.2) to turn those *bytes* into a string. *Most* systems these days are fine with strings containing null characters, and here they mark the delimiters, so if you want to split it into the individual strings, split on the nulls *after* the string conversion.

However, if you just want to store these strings and whatever DB you're working with is fine with null characters in strings, pass them through unchanged. Note: If you've not been using parameterized queries up until this point in accessing the database, now's the time to learn. Because it's often tricky to construct a string *literal* which contains a null character without having to do lots of manual re-processing and/or escaping. And it's generally a good habit.

---

Your string here should contain the characters `T`, `E`, `S`, `T`, null, `D`, `A`, `T`, `A`, null, null

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly the direction I needed.  Appreciate the push.